# Find Hierarchy for each Node

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm attempting to rebuild a stored procedure that current uses the "[RBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rbar/info)" method to map my organization's reporting hierarchy. When the organization was smaller, this method worked fine, but as the organization has grown, this method has not scaled well at all.

What I'd like to do is use a recursive CTE to help speed up the process. The first step that I've tried has worked; map each position in the hierarchy as it relates to the first/top node.

My data looks similar to this:

```
POSITION_NBR | REPORTS_TO |
     001           001
     002           001
     003           001
     004           002
     005           003
     006           003
     007           004
```

My current approach return this:

```
REPORTS_TO | POSITION_NBR | EMPLEVEL
    001           001          0
    001           002          1
    001           003          1
    002           004          2
    003           005          2
    003           006          2
    004           007          3
```

This is my SQL:

```
WITH POSN_HIERARCHY AS 
    (SELECT POS.REPORTS_TO
            ,POS.POSITION_NBR
            ,0 AS EMPLEVEL
    FROM dbo.POSITION_BASE POS
    WHERE POS.POSITION_NBR = POS.REPORTS_TO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT POS.REPORTS_TO
            ,POS.POSITION_NBR
            ,EMP.EMPLEVEL + 1
    FROM dbo.POSITION_BASE POS
    INNER JOIN POSN_HIERARCHY EMP
        ON EMP.POSITION_NBR = POS.REPORTS_TO
    WHERE POS.POSITION_NBR <> POS.REPORTS_TO)

SELECT * FROM POSN_HIERARCHY
```

What I'm struggling with is a way to not only find the hierarchy as it relates to the first node, but also *every* hierarchy within the main hierarchy. For example, my current SQL will find my level within the main organization's structure, but I also want to be able to see my level within my manager's hierarchy, and his manager's hierarchy, etc.

*So basically I'm trying to return a hierarchy for every manager in the organization.*

My ideal output would look like this:

```
REPORTS_TO | POSITION_NBR | EMPLEVEL
    001           001          0  
    001           002          1
    001           003          1
    001           004          2
    001           005          2
    001           006          2
    001           007          3
    002           004          1
    002           007          2
    003           005          1
    003           006          1
    004           007          1
```

So the output shows the level of every person with respect to each of the parent nodes above it. (007 is 3 levels from 001, 2 levels from 002, and 1 level from 004.)

I've tried modifying the anchor query so that it returns all managers, but that didn't work. I tried looking into multiple recursions within the CTE, but I can't get that to work either. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this, please?

Comment: Can edit the post with sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #POSITION_BASE(POSITION_NBR VARCHAR(20), REPORTS_TO VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #POSITION_BASE
SELECT '001','001'
UNION ALL
SELECT '002','001' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '003','001' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '004','002' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '005','003' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '006','003' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '007','004'
```

I have written the logic inside the query

```
;WITH POSN_HIERARCHY AS 
(
    -- This is your first query in question. There is no changes here.
    SELECT POS.REPORTS_TO ,POS.POSITION_NBR ,0 AS EMPLEVEL
    FROM #POSITION_BASE POS    
    WHERE POS.POSITION_NBR = POS.REPORTS_TO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT POS.REPORTS_TO ,POS.POSITION_NBR ,EMP.EMPLEVEL + 1
    FROM #POSITION_BASE POS
    INNER JOIN POSN_HIERARCHY EMP
        ON EMP.POSITION_NBR = POS.REPORTS_TO
    WHERE POS.POSITION_NBR <> POS.REPORTS_TO
 )
 ,CTE2 AS
 (
     -- There will be no change to top-level parent and the child just below it.
     -- We select the children whose primary level is greater than one
     SELECT POSITION_NBR,REPORTS_TO,0 EMP
     FROM POSN_HIERARCHY     
     WHERE EMPLEVEL > 1  

     UNION ALL

    -- Finds all the parents for the children whose primary level is greater than one
    SELECT CTE.POSITION_NBR ,C.REPORTS_TO ,EMP + 1
    FROM CTE2 CTE
    INNER JOIN POSN_HIERARCHY C  ON C.POSITION_NBR = CTE.REPORTS_TO
    WHERE C.POSITION_NBR <> C.REPORTS_TO 
 )
 -- We select the top-level parent and the child just below it
 SELECT REPORTS_TO REPORTS_TO,POSITION_NBR,EMPLEVEL
 FROM POSN_HIERARCHY
 WHERE EMPLEVEL < 2

 UNION

 -- We select the children whose primary level is greater than one and its parents
 -- and increment the number by one to meet our requirement
 SELECT REPORTS_TO ,POSITION_NBR,EMP + 1 EMP
 FROM CTE2 
 OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Since SQL FIDDLE has some internal error, you can see for the below image result.

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm unable to test right now, so I'll test it later and let you know my results. At first glance it looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Took the query 13 seconds to complete versus 19+ minutes! Thank you for the help!